# Bitmap memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, bitmap, garbage-collection

I'm having trouble with memory leaks from bitmaps. I need to load 20 random Drawables (from 50 possible) each time when Activity starts and draws my custom view.

This is part of initialization, where I declare Drawables

```
 resources = getResources();
    theme = context.getTheme();
    count = 20;
    degree = (2 * Math.PI) / count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        views.add(new CircleImageView(context));
    }
    int rand;
    Set<Integer> randomImages = new HashSet<>();
    Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    while (randomImages.size() < count) {
        rand = rnd.nextInt(50) + 1;
        randomImages.add(resources.getIdentifier("ph_" + rand, "drawable", "com.bitgenie.friends"));
    }
    randomImagesArray = new int[count];
   // int iter = 0;
    for (Integer i :
            randomImages) {
        drawables.add(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources,i,theme));
        //iter++;
    }
    randomImages.clear();
```

This runs only one time, when CustomView is created. 
I create Set to provide only unique resource ID. And you can see creation of CircleImageViews (de.hdodenhof:circleimageview).

Then in onLayout  method I setDrawable to each CircleImageView

```
for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++) {
final CircleImageView currentUserPic = views.get(i);
Glide.clear(currentUserPic);
Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext()).load("")
            .placeholder(drawables.get(i)).into(currentUserPic);
 }
```

I hoped that Glide will help with decreasing images size.
It was like this before

```
currentUserPic.setImageDrawable(drawables.get(i));
```

When activity calls onDestroy() I'm calling onDestroy() in my CustomView

```
public void onDestroy()
{
    for (CircleImageView v :
            views) {
        Glide.clear(v);
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)v.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        v.setImageDrawable(null);
        v.setImageBitmap(null);
        v = null;
        b.recycle();
    }

    for (Drawable drawable :
            drawables) {
        ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap().recycle();
        drawable = null;
    }
    drawables.clear();
    rouletteImage.setImageBitmap(null);
    rouletteImage.setImageDrawable(null);
    rouletteImage = null;
    views.clear();
    this.removeAllViews();
}
```

I tried to recycle everything I could, even tried to call System.gc(), but it didn't help. After all of this Bitmaps (from Drawables) are still in memory. If I'll use "Cause GC" from Android Studio it'll free a lot of memory (80mb -> 30mb).

Comment: System.gc() does not guarantee that the garbage collector is run. It is more of a suggestion than an execution. Unfortunately in Java you are at the mercy of the system, which will free memory when it sees fit. If more memory is really necessary for your app, you can put `android:largeHeap="true"` in the application element of you AndroidManifest.xml